# Using a switch statement to change the output of an element

Tags: powershell

I need some help please.

I have an array which imports csv data from a report. The data contains, Server Name, start time and Final Task status code.

```
ServerName     Start Time           Final task Code
SERVER1        07/11/2017 01:35:30        19                                                                                   
SERVER2        07/11/2017 01:35:31        19                                                                 SERVER3        07/11/2017 01:35:33        6**
```

I believe I need to write a switch statement to change the Final task code into something more userfriend. `Code 19 = Successful`, `Code 6 = Error`

I wrote the following switch statement:

```
switch ($Successrate.FinalJobStatus){
    19 {"100% Success"}
    6 {"Error"}
}
```

This will change the onscreen output as expected, however I am struggling to make the output of Final Task code to read `100% success` or `Error` instead of `19` and `6`.

Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
$Successcutofdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$Successrate = import-csv C:\ITO\RB\PROD\Reports\Success.csv | Where-Object ({$_.ActualStartTime -as [datetime] -gt $Successcutofdate}) |select-Object @{n='Server Name';e={$_.ResourceName }},   @{n='Start Time';e={$_.ActualStartTime}} , FinalJobStatus| Sort-Object "Server Name"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use calculated properties like the ones you did in the same line :

```
$Successcutofdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$Successrate = import-csv C:\ITO\RB\PROD\Reports\Success.csv | Where-Object ( {$_.ActualStartTime -as [datetime] -gt $Successcutofdate}) | Select-Object @{n='Server Name';e={$_.ResourceName }}, @{n='Start Time';e={$_.ActualStartTime}}, @{n='FinalJobStatus';e={switch ($_.FinalJobStatus){ 19 {"100% Success"} 6 {"Error"}}}} | Sort-Object "Server Name"
```

Comment: Perfect - thankyou. I was close , i just struggled getting the correct formatting. Thank you very much